# Unique index by VARCHAR(1023) vs by BINARY(32)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table of unique urls (~70M records, an average urls length is 51 chars):

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uri` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
  `uri_hash` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i_1` (`short_url_code`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `i_2` (`uri`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

uri_hash = hash(uri)
```

It was created when MySQL did not support long unique indexes. Now we have MySQL 5.7 and I think about optimisation, but I'm not sure wich way is better:

1. remove `uri_hash` column and make index `i_2` longer (1023), and update `uri` column to support different cases (upper/lower) `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin`
2. remove index `i_2` that we don't use and search by `uri_hash`

   a. leave `uri_hash varchar(64)`

   b. convert to `uri_hash binary(32)`
3. leave as is

I have done some benchmarks, but I have not found significant difference between these variants: the same 60 reads + 60 writes actions per second in one thread

This table will grow up to ~200M records.

Can you suggest what variant is better?

Comment: 2 seem to be good one as with about 200M records it may not be a good idea to index uri_hash(255), have you tested with 200M records?..do run optimize/analyze table before you do benchmarking

Comment: @NawazSohail, I tested it with 70M records and have not found a difference in performance. Average links length is 51 chars.

Answer (score 3):

First, I must point out why this is *bad*:

```
UNIQUE KEY `i_2` (`uri`(255))
```

It constrains only the first 255 characters of `uri` to be unique.  That is, you cannot have two rows that agree in the first 255 characters, but differ after that.

Where is `short_url_code`?

Back to the question... Answer: "none of the above".  But here are some tips on improving performance:

If you need a uniqueness constraint on a too-long column, here is one approach:

Use `UNHEX(MD5(uri))` in a `BINARY(16)`.  Then make that the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.

For those who complain that `MD5` might have dups, I point out that "If you have 9 trillion rows, there is only one chance in 9 trillion that the next row you insert will be a false dup."

So, I would have only these two indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(md5_uri),
INDEX(uri(44))
```

The secondary index assumes you need to look up uri prefixes when you don't know the full string.  The `44` was somewhat arbitrarily picked -- smaller to save space; larger to have fewer dups.  More important than the `average of 51` you mentioned is "what is the shortest length that leads to a 'reasonably small' number of dups for each prefix."

The problem with any type of hash is the inability to cache the data (and/or index) after the data (or index) becomes bigger than can fit in cache (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`).

My suggested changes will

- shrink amount of cache needed by getting rid of an index and a column, and
- have only 1 uniqueness constraint (instead of 3) to check during `INSERT`.

But you still need more ram than the dataset size, so that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` has space for caching all the data.  Else, you will stuck with being as slow as your disk drive (which should like a slow spinning drive at 60/sec.)  Are there more columns in the table than what you listed?  If so, we might consider *vertical* partitioning.

That leaves another problem that you alluded to -- case folding.  No hash is impervious to case without help.  You might do `UNHEX(MD5(LOWER(uri)))`.  But that will also strip accents in utf8.  Not knowing your full set of requirements here, I cannot discuss further.

Another thing to do is to avoid the at-least-one I/O that occurs with every transaction.  Where practical, batch inserts, group things between `BEGIN..COMMIT`, and/or set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` (instead of the default of 1).  SSDs would also help.

Comment: 16GB of RAM will probably suffice for now; 32 or 48 will be needed for when you have 200M rows.

Comment: `UNIQUE KEY i_2 (uri(255))` - it's old solution. Now I think about `UNIQUE KEY i_2 (uri(1023))` vs `UNIQUE KEY i_2 (md5_uri(16)) + uri column without index`

Comment: "It's old solution" -- Shrinking the data and cutting out indexes are parts of the solution I am advocating.

Comment: I can't remove `PRIMARY KEY (id)` because it is needed for future migrations (using LHM, pt-online-schema-change or gh-ost)

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is better: `id + varchar(1023) + binary(16) + unique key by binary(16)` or `id + varchar utf8_bin (1023) + unique key by varchar(1023)`, but I have not found the answer yet

Comment: And I am saying "neither".